# write the python statement that would print out "abc","def",and. "ghi" in column format in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

**Input: ABCDEFGHIJKLIMNOQRSTUVWXYZ**

This is my input. Now I want my output to print in this format:

Expected Output:
ABC
DEF
GHI
JKL
MNO
PQR
STU
VWX
YZ

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. We can help with problems in your code, but we don't do your homework for you. Please see [ask].

Answer (score 1):

```
count = 0
for char in input_str:
    count +=1
    if count % 3 == 0:
        print(char, end=' ')
    else:
        print(char, end='')
```